# Separate a whole number horizontally e.g 1234 -> 1 2 3 4

Tags: java

The guidelines say:

> Do not use conditional if nor loops (e.g. for) for this question nor arrays, etc.  Use the basic 5 arithmetic operators (+ - * / %) only for each digit separation.

I can make the list vertically, just not horizontally.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SeparateDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a full number: ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        
        separateAndPrintDigits(number);
        
        scanner.close();
    }
    
    public static void separateAndPrintDigits(int number) {
        // Convert the number to a string to easily separate digits
        String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
        
        System.out.println("Separating digits:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberStr.length(); i++) {
            char digit = numberStr.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code that does that vertically, so we can start from there.

Comment: System.out.println(String.join(" ", "Hello, World!".split("")));

Comment: `for (; number > 0; number \= 10) System.out.print(number % 10);`

Comment: No `if`, no `for`, no `while` makes this kind of difficult to solve, because this essentially prevents you from knowing when you are done separating, doesn't it? Are you allowed to use `switch`? `switch` could be used as a complicated way to enforce a condition (i.e. `if` substitute).

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. You're almost there (even if you strayed away from the original request of only using arithmetic operators). Check out the difference between [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char)) and [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char))

Comment: But since you can't use `for` etc, check out Bohemian's comment up here. You can do that same thing manually without a loop if the number always have four digits.

Comment: As this looks like some kind of homework or test, please add also your knowledge level in Java (as you see yourself) so we have the chance to find a suitable solution and also the necessary grade of explanations. And please add the assignment with a bit more details to your question, even if "the title says it all" it would look better.

Comment: @Randy the guidelines say "no arrays", but `String.split` returns an array.

Comment: for avoiding loops we can use recursion; but not using any conditional like `if` or the conditional operator (`? :`) makes it tricky (and not the best programming practice)

Comment: @user85421 I think the recursion end can be handled by a `try ... catch`, something like provoking a division by zero should be OK

Comment: "I can make the list vertically, just not horizontally." Then use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` (and don't forget to add spaces)

Comment: By the way, you haven't done "Use the basic 5 arithmetic operators (+ - * / %) only for each digit separation." correctly. It wants you to use math operations, not splitting a String into characters.

Comment: @Kaddath an example of what I meant with "tricky"  and "not best practice"

Comment: A Java 8 Streams approach: `IntStream.iterate(n, i -> i/10).limit((int)Math.log10(n)+1).map(i -> i%10).boxed().collect(Collector.of(StringBuilder::new, (s,i) -> s.insert(0, i).insert(1," "), StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::toString)).trim()` (no Exception... but some hidden loops? conditionals?)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression this way:

```java
int number = 1234;
String stringified = String.valueof(number);
System.out.println(stringified.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d)", "$0 "));
```

This will show `1 2 3 4`.

This replaces each diget (`\\d`) that is followed by another digit (`(?=\\d)`) with itself (`$0` group 0 is the whole match) followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is more to this than what you have described. You may need to clarify the constraints with your instructor as using loops and if statements are a fundamental part of writing software.  But here is an example that satisfies your requirements but it is contrived and not a good practice.

- use recursion, that avoids the loop.
- artificially induce a runtime exception to stop the process.

The `for loop` is just to demonstrate and not part of the actual solution.

```
for (int v : new int[] {123, 2345, 1, 123456780}) {
    System.out.println(separateDigits(v));
}
```

prints

```
1 2 3 
2 3 4 5 
1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
```

Using recursion, the values are computed in reverse order of what you want. But when returning from the exception. The string is built in the proper order and eventually returned as the result.

```
public static String separateDigits(int v) {
    try {
        int q = 10/v; // force exception when v == 0
        return separateDigits(v/10) + v%10 + " ";
    } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThomasBehr Yeah.  Good point.  It's detritus.  I did this rather quickly with one thought; changed gears and didn't clean up. Updated.  Thanks!.

Comment: I knew a try...catch would do the job, I wonder where the question comes from, and what is the expected answer, it looks too convoluted for a homeworks question, maybe a coding challenge thing?

Comment: @Kaddath You're right.  Didn't notice your comment above until now.  And I agree.  I hope this isn't being taught as there are many reasonable assignments that could be given.